# How can I remove GNOME shell(desktop environment) but remain Unity?

Tags: desktop-environments

I am current using Ubuntu 13.10 dist and I'm very happy to use Unity than Gnome shell. Now I would like to remove gnome shell completely and install Cinnamon desktop(I just want Unity and Cinammon in my selection) into ubuntu Dist. What is the safety way to do that?

Comment: you can use `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*` to remove gnome shell completely.

Comment: @Guru will it affect unity??

Comment: It should not affect unity.

Answer (score 0):

By default your ubuntu has unity unless you removed it.

for removing gnome

```
sudo aptitude remove gnome-shell
```

and then you may need reboot or just logout and login by unity desktop.

Comment: is that `aptitude` installed by default?

Comment: @Avinash Raj. Maybe not. If so you can use `apt-get remove/purg ...`

Comment: I scare it will affecting the unity environment? what will be unity like after remove gnome-shell?

Comment: If the unity is installed, Be cool, Nothing to worry about it. The unity installed besides other desktop environments.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of cinnamon conflict with gnome packages which is presumably why you want to remove gnome. I don't have gnome installed to check this but on my Debian, installing cinnamon automatically removes gnome. So, almost certainly, running this will be enough:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Test it first by running it in simulate mode:

```
sudo apt-get -s install cinnamon
```

That will show you the packages that will be installed or removed. There should be along list of gnome packages that will be removed there. If you see such a list, just go ahead and install cinnamon.

Comment: Cinnamon having crashed after installed,mouse click does not work. :(