# How to do clean install with only Cinnamon desktop

Tags: gnome, cinnamon

My 16.10 system running Gnome desktop crashed during the 17.04 upgrade, so I'm going to do a fresh install, which I'd like to switch to Cinnamon.  On another Gnome system, Cinnamon installed fine, but I had a lot of conflicts--settings, default applications, etc.

So what I'd like to do is a clean install of Cinnamon desktop, but remove other conflicts.  I've found some related questions.

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448569/how-can-i-remove-gnome-shelldesktop-environment-but-remain-unity) tells how to remove Gnome, but is a bit dated.  Plus I tried something similar on my other box, and it removed too much, creating problems getting back to a running system.

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936590/cinnamon-install-broken-in-17-04-black-background-icons-not-changing) on the other hand is more recent but following the links 2 levels deep for a UEFI system is pretty involved, and I need to do this without spending all day on it.  Booting to stick, backing up data, and re-installing (without overwriting Win10 of course) is going to take enough time that I don't have!

Is there a good way to install only cinnamon, or cleanly remove all remnants of the first intall?

Comment: Arguably a good way is to start with the minimal ISO, and add whatever you want. Removing Gnome is a bit misleading, since Cinnamon is based on Gnome, and needs its packages.

Comment: How about installing Ubuntu with no desktop environment(Ubuntu server edition) and then install cinnamon.Not posting as ab answer cause I didn't tried it yet.

Comment: @mikewhatever--That second link is the minimal ISO process, but it points out that ISO doesn't support booting UEFI (only BIOS).

Comment: @mikewhatever-- Because Cinnamon is a fork of Gnome, I figured most dependencies were already installed.  Everything worked for the most part in the other system, but it's the Cinnamon tweaks that cause problems.  For example, when I put in a memory stick, Nautilus launched instead of Nemo.   I had hoped when I removed Gnome, apt would recognize the cinnamon meta-package had been installed and not remove any dependencies, but  it didn't go that well.  :-/

Comment: @SMITPATIL--May try something like that.  Have to see what the server install actually gives me to work with.